# Conditionally add query operator on properties defined in non-EDM base type, if inheriting

Tags: entity-framework, generics, inheritance

(C# code at end of question)

I have the following inheritance chain:

```
PreRecord <- Record <- (multiple entity types)
```

`Record` declares a property `ID As Integer`.

`PreRecord` and `Record` are not EDM types, and do not correspond to tables in the database.

I have a method that takes a generic parameter constrained to `PreRecord` and builds an EF query with the generic parameter as the element type. At runtime, in the event that `T` inherits not just from `PreRecord` but from `Record`, I would like add an `OrderBy` operator on `ID`:

```
'Sample 1
Function GetQuery(Of T As PreRecord)(row As T) As IQueryable(Of T)
    Dim dcx = New MyDbContext
    Dim qry = dcx.Set(Of T).AsQueryable
    If TypeOf row Is RecordBase Then
        'modify/rewrite the query here

    End If
    Return qry
End Function
```

If the parameter constraint were to `Record` I would have no problem applying query operators that use the `ID` property. How can I make use of a different (narrowing) generic constraint mid-method and still return an `IQueryable(Of T)` / `IQueryable<T>`, where `T` is still constrained to `PreRecord`?

---

I tried this:

```
'Sample 2
qry = dcx.Set(Of T).Cast(Of Record).OrderBy(Function(x) x.ID).Cast(Of PreRecord)()
```

which doesn't work:

> LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

---

C# equivalent:

```
//Sample 1
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(T row) where T : PreRecord {
    var dcx = new MyDbContext();
    var qry = dcx.Set<T>.AsQueryable();
    if (row is RecordBase) {
        //modify/rewrite the query here
    }
    return qry;
}
```

and this doesn't work:

```
//Sample 2
qry = dcx.Set<T>.Cast<Record>.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Cast<PreRecord>()
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities supports only entity types.  If you want to use your own types then you must evaluate the LINQ to Entities query, e.g. by calling `ToArray` or `ToList`, and then use LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @jmcilhinney True. But if the method's generic parameter constraint was to `Record` then I would have no problem querying on properties declared in `Record`. But now that the method's constraint is to `PreRecord` how can I query on `Record` properties? (Updated the question.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the fact that compiler checks queries already at compile time and PreRecord class does not have ID property. We cannot use simply Cast, because when it is used in definition of the query parser tries to convert it to sql - but there is no such thing that exists in sql. Sql supports only conversion of one column type to another - so on the .NET side it is supported only for primitive and enum types. To overcome compiler query checking we may use Expression class to build dynamic queries:

```
ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Record));
Expression body = Expression.Property(e, "ID");
Expression<Func<PreRecord, int>> orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<PreRecord, int>>(body, e);
```

And use your expression in the query:

```
qry = dcx.Set<T>.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
```

This way your linq query will not be validated during compile time but execution time. Here I assumed ID is of type int, if the type is different change it accordingly.